# Script editor inside a web page

Tags: webapp-rec

I need to edit some scripts from a web app, at the moment i'm using a plain textarea and it works.
The main problem is that these scripts have indentations so i'd like to simply press TAB to control the indentation level when writing some new code and possibly automatically start next lines with the same indentation. In a normal textarea pressing TAB switches the focus to the next object.

I'm looking for something like tinyMCE but that is made specifically for scripts.
The minimum required functionality is to handle the indentation level, other cool things would be syntax highlighting and hinting/completition but they're not really necessary.

Comment: Like [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that "Javascript" frame. How can i get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) is the library used by jsFiddle and it works very well. It supports many languages and has a lot of options like keymaps and markers. Awesome!